# An error occurred with ayamapp. Please try again later

Tags: php, facebook

I am php code for a facebook api app

I kept the same login key and secret key.

but when I run the code:

A pop up will appear asking for you to login to facebook. If you can`t see the pop up, please allow pop up from your browser, then reload this page

and when the popup window opens

An error occurred with ayamapp. Please try again later.

and when I change the stored api key/secret

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 0):

can you post your php code? it sounds to me like you didn't set up your app all the way on facebook... You have to be sure to save your app domain on your account at developers.facebook.com.  Facebook will ONLY redirect to that domain,